# Many-to-many relations from table to itself in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to represent a relationship between authors. I'd like to have authors related to other authors (coauthorshp), with extra data in the relation, such that with an author `a` I can find their coauthors.

How this is done between two different objects is this:

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(80))
    child = relationship('Child', backref='parent_assocs')

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Association', backref='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

but how would I do this in my case?

The nature of a coauthorship is that it is bidirectional. So, when you insert the tuple `(id_left, id_right)` into the coauthorship table through a coauthoship object, is there a way to also insert the reverse relation easily? I'm asking because I want to use association proxies.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you are trying to do? Reading your question kind of makes sense, but need more information.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to literally have pairs of rows in `association`, that is, for every `id_left, id_right` that's inserted, you also insert an `id_right, id_left`, you'd use an [attribute event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html?highlight=attribute%20event#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append) to listen for append events on either side, and produce an append in the other direction.

If you just want to be able to navigate between Parent/Child in either direction, just a single row of `id_left, id_right` is sufficient.   The examples in the docs regarding this kind of mapping illustrate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLAlchemy (and probably also outside of it) this is called a self-referential table and the method of choice in most cases (according to SQLAlchemy's docs) is to use an adjacency list relationship. See [Adjacency List Relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/self_referential.html) in the SQLAlchemy docs.

For a many-to-many self-referential relation, you should also have a look at the [Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many) documentation.